# using bash variable in perl command in bash

Tags: bash, perl

I need to pass a variable to a Perl statement from a bash script through sqlplus, to edit a file. It works fine without passing the `count` variable but encounters a problem when passing it.

```
count=$( sqlplus -s test/test <<-EOF
    set pagesize 0;
    set feedback off;
    set verify off;
    set heading off echo off;
        select count(*) from test;
    exit;
EOF)

if [ "$count" != "" ] && [ $count != "0" ]; then

    perl -lpe 'print "Total Number of Rejected Files = "$count"" if $. == 10' Results.txt >> data.txt

else

fi
```

As far as I know, my problem only with this part `"$count"`. I have tried a lot of things like :

`perl -lpe 'print "Total Number of Rejected Files = $ENV{'count'}" if $. == 10' Results.txt >> data.txt`

and this :

`perl -lpe 'print "Total Number of Rejected Files = $ENV{count}" if $. == 10' Results.txt >> data.txt`

but the problem is that the bash variable does not expand through the perl statement.

Comment: Your perl code is expecting to process `Results.txt` but you don't seem to declare or use that anywhere

Comment: right, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `$ENV` approach will work just fine, you just need to export the shell variable first. Your perl script is running in a subshell, so the only way it will see the variable is if you export it first:

```bsh
count=$( sqlplus -s test/test <<-EOF
    set pagesize 0;
    set feedback off;
    set verify off;
    set heading off echo off;
        select count(*) from test;
    exit;
EOF)

export count

if [ "$count" != "" ] && [ $count != "0" ]; then
    perl -lpe 'print "Total Number of Rejected Files = $ENV{count}" if $. == 10' Results.txt >> data.txt
fi
```

I am a bit confused about your perl command though. `perl -lpe '' Results.txt` means "print each line of Results.txt after applying the script given by `-e` to it. But you aren't actually doing anything to Results.txt, so what's the point?

Your code will simply print out every line of `Results.txt` and then, on the 10th line, it will also print `Total Number of Rejected Files =` and the value of `$count`. If that's really what you want to do, then great. It just seems very unlikely that you would in fact want this.

Comment: I am not familiar with `perl`: how do hard quotes not suppress (shell) variable expansion here? Am I mixing things up?

Comment: @Fiximan essentially, yes. Perl is a programming language, not a shell tool, so the internal `$` are its own variables. Here, by exporting the shell variable, we make it available to the Perl environment which can see all shell environment variables in the hash `%ENV`.

Comment: So `$ENV{var}` draws the `var` form the environment - makes sense like this. Thanks.

Comment: @terdon it Inserts a new line at specific line number, here im just trying to insert  a new line at line `10` , also it acts like `positional command arguments:` `perl -lpe 'BEGIN{$n=shift; $s=shift}; print $s if $. == $n' 10 "Total Number of Rejected Files = $ENV{count}" file`,  your solution above works fine but the problem output looks like: `Total Number of Rejected Files =                        1`thers several tabs between = and 1how can i avoid these spaces?

Comment: @NikolanAsad I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. Yes, your command will print out `Total Number...` at line 10. If that is what you want, then great. It just seems like an odd requirement. There is nothing here that would insert tabs, if you see tabs, then they were already there in your input. Most probably in the `$count` variable.  Also, your `shift` commands won't do anything, your `@ARGV` array is empty.